# How to set Lift run mode on App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, scala, lift

I'm successfully running a Lift 2.4 app on App Engine. I only have problems with the **run mode**.

Lift determines the run mode, *production* or *development*, via:

```
System.getProperty("run.mode")
```

The only way to set a property on App Engine is via:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="run.mode" value="production"/>
</system-properties>
```

BUT now when I start the App Engine development server locally, it's also in *production mode*.

I tried overriding it by specifying a system property on JVM start or Lift boot, didn't work.

**How can I have *production mode* in the Cloud and *development mode* locally?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using different configuration file for different environment (production/development).

Take a look at your build tool manual to find how exactly you can handle configuration file per environment.

For maven:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html

Comment: you're right, that's indeed the only possible solution. Thanks! :-)